# Direct and reliable access to framebuffer under X

Tags: x11, framebuffer

I have the following problem: I need to develop an application that will run both on 
linux and freebsd, preferably in an X environment.
This application will have to draw very simple graphic primitives (say lines) with a strong
contraint: no matter the hardware and the os, I need to be able to read what has been 
written to the videomemory back and that must match per pixel what I expect having written.
To be more clear, two instances of this program running on different machines with different video cards and different os, must write the very same pixels to the videomemory and must retrieve back exactly the same memory (a part from some constant conversion in the pixel format), so that if I memcmp them, they matches.

I think the easiest way of doing this is accessing directly the videomemory both for writing and reading and to avoid going through any rasterizer which I can not control.
So I was guessing which is the easiest and most modern way of doing it in X.

thanks!

Comment: The rasterizer of X11 is guaranteed to work in a consistent, system-independent manner, unless you specify line width of 0. But why do you want to read the framebuffer? You cannot reliably get your drawing back, as any window can be obscured, moved offscreen etc, and the invisible parts are lost for good.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to read it. I want to catch those situations.:-). Anyway, when you say "the rasterizer of X11", do you mean drawing lines using xlib? What if I just want to set the pixel values directly? I saw DGA, but I read it is obsolete now but I can't still figure out what's the non obsolete solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I mean lines with Xlib. You said you want to draw lines.